# next/cache not found in NextJS 13.3.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to follow directions to revalidateTag in NodeJS runtime as [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/revalidateTag) but there is no next/cache installed when `npm i` is executed on NextJS 13.3.4.

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { revalidateTag } from 'next/cache';
 
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  const tag = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get('tag');
  revalidateTag(tag);
  return NextResponse.json({ revalidated: true, now: Date.now() });
}
```

How can I use this feature?

Comment: Did you try exporting `revalidateTag` from `next/server` as in the first example?

Comment: Yes, but the only thing I see there is `unstable_revalidateTag`. I suppose I could use that but I know I have a NodeJS runtime on Vercel, so not sure if that's what I should be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update your Next.js to the latest 13.4.2. That feature was just added.